# I find css layout very unintuitive; Is there a good drag-and-drop tool I can use?

Tags: css, user-interface, layout

I find css layout very unintuitive; table layouts make more sense but are frowned upon. Is there a good simple article or drag-and-drop tool I can use that will clarify this for me once and for all?

Comment: would be nice! with chrome developer tools or firebug, you can change parameters and add rules and have the changes take place instantly (on keyup as soon as the rule is valid). That's not what you want but is a fast way to learn. The fact that you can use these tools to screw around with other website's CSS this way too is big plus.

Comment: LOL!  Really, there's *nothing*?  Thanks for the suggestions.  I've used firebug and also CSS Edit, but I've never seen a drag-and-drop tool for this.  I'm a little surprised that it just doesn't exist.  Maybe I should build it.  Thanks.

Comment: Learn how to use CSS. Oh and table layout makes no sense.

Comment: Unless you meant `display: table;`.

Comment: @Alerty What I meant is that table layout makes conceptual sense because you're laying things out in a grid, "this goes there", "that goes there", it's intuitive and natural. Now I understand that the web dev community looks down on table based layouts because you're using the table tag for something it was never intended to do. But, regardless, laying things out in in a grid is far more natural and intuitive than all this 'float' business in CSS which I think is a conceptual nightmare. ;)

Comment: @RobertHume I find it ironic that you would say "laying things out in a grid". You can create layers by using CSS and a multitude of tags such as `<div>`, `<header>`, `<section>`, `<footer>` and so on. I can understand that CSS can be difficult to grasp by all the liberty given with the different properties. From my point of view, using tables for layout can easily become a `<th>`, `<tr>`, `<td>` nightmare and become exponentially difficult to manage. Just imagine a site such as StackOverflow made entirely with tables. I have an headache just imagining such a thing!

Comment: @Alerty I hear you. Where I'm coming from is I've done a lot of Java Swing development and I have intimate knowledge of all the Swing layout managers; GridLayout, BorderLayout, CardLayout, GridBagLayout, and so on. CSS layout just doesn't seem intuitive or come to me easily but just about everything else makes 'conceptual' sense to me. All that being said, for the Java layouts (especially GridBag) I had formal training and practice, so I guess that's what I need for CSS. Feels it should be easier. All that `float` and `clear` stuff never seems to work the way I expect it to. Stay cool!

Answer (score 0):

Not necessarily a WYSIWYG CSS Editor but a good template tool that generates pretty good CSS is [Artisteer](http://www.artisteer.com/)

Apart from that , as always practice makes perfect. It took a while for me to transition from tables based to CSS based layout but it was worth the effort. my HTML is now a lot leaner. Redesigns are a lot easier as the HTML has very little if anything to do with the visual design of the page/site. There were many hybrid designs using a mix of tables and CSS in the interim and there are still times when a table is required.

Answer (score 0):

I don't like it, but there always [Adobe Muse](http://www.adobe.com/products/muse.html)...

Do yourself a huge favour though and just learn CSS!